# Эффективный поиск

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Есть база данных предприятий 1000 записей
Есть форма, в которой нужно выбрать одно из предприятий из списка и потом что-то с ним делать (не важно что)
Как организовать эффективный выбор из такого кол-ва строк?
Например они все находятся в комбобоксе и мы начинаем вводить название в комбобокс и у нас сразу отфильтровывает лишнее. Как сделать это отзывчиво и красиво ? 
Хотя бы натолкните на путь. Реализацию сам придумаю.

Comment: Гуглите виртуализацию http://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/14.5.php

Comment: Используйте [AutoComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode(v=vs.110).aspx). Ещё [ссылка](http://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/WinForms20.xml#E3B).

Comment: Уточните у вас `WinForms` или `WPF`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать `AutoComplete`. Например поставить комбобоксу `myCMB.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend` и `AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource`. Это позволит автоматически сортировать выпадающий список.

Comment: Авто завершение хорошо. Но если название предприятий будет в виде ООО "Колосок" - придется вводить ООО "К... чтобы выдало как минимум предприятия на букву К, это не очень удобно. Компоратора своего я так понял нельзя прикрутить ?

Comment: Для этого надо заморочиться как [тут](http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/183328/AutoComplete-Like-Search-ComboBox-control-in-Windows-Forms-Application/)

Comment: Немного поясню:в комбобоксе после срабатывания события KeyPress надо отфильтровать данные и уже их вставить в список

Comment: Тоже вариант, кстати самый менее трудозатратный :) Если использовать LINQ

Comment: Можно вопрос, вот я отфильтровал по первой нажатой букве, осталось, допустим, 200 вариантов. Я их занес в DataSourсe комбобокса и автоматом выбрался элемент. А мне это не нужно. Работает как-то не корректно.

Comment: @Chelios , попробуй SuggestAppend заменить на Suggest

Answer (score 2):

В Wpf я делал так:
Xaml:

```
 <Label Content="Searched text:"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FilterString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
            </Grid>
            <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" Width="40*" SortDirection="Ascending"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Version" Binding="{Binding Version, Mode=OneWay}" Width="10*" />                    
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Code:

```
    private ICollectionView _myList;

     public ICollectionView MyList
     {
        get { return _myList; }
        set
        {
           _myList = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged("MyList");
        }
     }

    private string _filterString = string.Empty;
    public bool FilterTask(object value)
    {
       var entry = value as MyListModel;
       return entry != null && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_filterString) || 
entry.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains(_filterString.ToLower()));
    }           

    public string FilterString
    {
      get { return _filterString; }
      set
      {
          _filterString = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged("FilterString");
           if (_myList != null)
              _myList.Refresh();
       }
    }
```

работает с 3000 записями быстро. Тут фильтром выступает текст бокс и фильтрует таблицу, но вы можете изменить реализацию под себя.

Ах да, в конструкторе при присваивании коллекции значений нужно указать:

```
MyList.Filter = FilterTask;
```

Comment: Попробую, спасибо за совет